# Android NDK and ANSI C

Tags: android-ndk

I started using andoid ndk and found some examples how to use it. They showed some easy code written in C++ and it's obvious. It's known that android ndk allows to write code in C++.

But is it possible to write the code in  ANSI C, not in C++, for android ndk?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can write C code. There is nothing that prevents you to do so. All NDK native API is actually C API.

Comment: But I can write in C++ as well. How do tell the compiler I want to use C insted of C++?

Comment: If you compile with gcc, C is assumed; if you use g++, C++. For more options, check [these](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Dialect-Options.html) command-line parameters.

Comment: By default file ending with cc, cp, cxx, cpp, CPP, c++ or C extensions will be assumed and compiled as C++ code. File with c extension will be compiled as C code. Here is full list: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Overall-Options.html#Overall-Options